# Codeigniter session issue while use more than one project in localhost

Tags: codeigniter

I seen one issue of session/cookie while using more than one project of codeigniter in localhost.  I means suppose if i have created login module in one website hosted in http://localhost/site1  and i login in http://localhost/site2 where i also use same code except different database and different $config['encryption_key'] then still my session/cookies are expired in site1. Only one site's cookies/session are working in codeigniter in localhost.

Can you help me , how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change sess_cookie_name value from $config in application/config/config.php file

Answer (score 1):

Make these values different for each site in `application/config/config.php`

ex. for site1

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'site1_cookies';
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'site1_sessions';
```

for site2

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'site2_cookies';
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'site2_sessions';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

In your application/config config.php

change config url like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_folder_name/'
```

And config index_page replace with blank like this :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';//'index.php';
```

And change your cookies path as well like this:

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'your_prefix';
$config['cookie_domain']    = 'localhost';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/project_floder_name/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

If you still facing any problem please comment below.